# IllegalStateException: The type registry TypeRegistry (Spring Boot + Spring Loaded + Java 8)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hotdeploy

I am trying to configure Spring Boot (1.3.3) + Spring Loaded (1.2.5 or 1.2.6) using Java 8 update 65 but I'm facing some problems when I change some Java class I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The type registry TypeRegistry(id=1252261311,loader=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader) does not know about type id 524
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.getReloadableType(TypeRegistry.java:1910) ~[springloaded-1.2.6.BUILD-20160411.195630-9.jar:1.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.idyrun(TypeRegistry.java:1789) ~[springloaded-1.2.6.BUILD-20160411.195630-9.jar:1.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at br.com.ProjectClass]
```

At line "at br.com.ProjectClass" there is one call to a lambda expression like this:

```
LOG.fine(()-> "Some text.."  );
```

After that, my application stops! I don't know if this problem is related with Lambda Expressions.

Any help?

Comment: I think there is bug for Spring Loaded with lambda expressions: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/165

Comment: As @Hrabosch mentioned above, this seems to be caused by a Spring Loaded bug. Fortunately it seems to be fixed with Spring Loaded 1.2.8. I had the same issue and it works for me using the SNAPSHOT.jar.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by a bug in Spring Loaded (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/165).

For me it was fixed with Spring Loaded 1.2.8 (see [here](https://repo.spring.io/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/libs-snapshot-local/org/springframework/springloaded/1.2.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/springloaded-1.2.8.BUILD-20170322.175731-1.jar)).